# 404 error with "/" request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

ihave a problem with my project `yous` when i put: `http://localhost:8080/yous/cc` it's works but with `http://localhost:8080/yous/` i got `404 error`

```
déc. 26, 2013 8:37:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
Avertissement: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/yous/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cc")
public String printWelcome() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    return "/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String printIndex() {
    return "index.html";

}
```

My web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>appServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my appServlet-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: you are mapping to http://localhost:8080/yous/// which is wrong i guess.

Comment: yes i'm mapping it because i want a welcome page. and why it's wrong ?

Comment: You have to use <welcome-file-list> element in the web.xml for this task.

Comment: servlet-mapping should be /** and welcome file should be <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

Comment: with just `<url-pattern>/**</url-pattern` without `<welcome-file>` it works now. thanks but why `/**` and not `/` ?

Comment: /* is used for path mapping. / maps to the default servlet of the application, it should have worked with regular servlets, I'm not sure why it did not work with spring, their mapping could be different.

Comment: oh wahit i just test `/cc` and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you look higher up in your logs, you should see the paths (and the handlers) that were registered. Post those.

Comment: what log ? in tomcat log ?

Comment: Does your controller have an `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: of course, you can see my detail config in the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

We resolve the problem with

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index")
```

It seems that `/index` handle `/`, can somebody explain me why ?